# Is it possible to insert text in a column conditionally in Power BI?

Tags: json, mongodb, powerbi, powerquery

I am working on a project where I am pulling data from Mongo DB.
I have a JSON source which is missing **double quotes(")** at some places.

```
[{_id:00000000000000000000000000000000,Action:"FeedbackGiven",Date:2020-12-10 18:17:32.792},
{_id:00000000000000000000000000000000,Action:"FeedbackGiven",Date:2020-12-10 19:02:24.604},
{_id:00000000000000000000000000000000,Action:"FeedbackGiven",Date:2020-12-10 19:16:16.615}]
```

I want to add **double quotes(")** for **_id** & **Date** values, so my data should look like

```
[{_id:"00000000000000000000000000000000",Action:"FeedbackGiven",Date:"2020-12-10 18:17:32.792"},
{_id:"00000000000000000000000000000000",Action:"FeedbackGiven",Date:"2020-12-10 19:02:24.604"},
{_id:"00000000000000000000000000000000",Action:"FeedbackGiven",Date:"2020-12-10 19:16:16.615"}]
```

Without **double quotes(")** Power BI is not able to recognize the data and is not able to Parse the JSON format to regular columns. I can't hardcode the **double quotes(")** based on character positions as the data is an array and the number of objects in the array is dynamic.

Is there a solution for my issue ?

Thanks & Regards,

Pratik

Comment: If you are able to edit as a string I would prefer trying replacing like replace _id: with _id:" and replace ,Action: with ",Action ......

Comment: Hi @MichalPalko,

Yes, this works, Thanks a lot :)

Best Regards,
Pratik

Comment: Great, please accept the answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to edit as a string I would prefer trying replacing like replace _id: with _id:" and replace ,Action: with ",Action ......